# XSLT check node availability in

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using XSLT 1.0 in my project. In my XSLT transformation I have to check for a specific element and if that exists - I have to perform some concatenation or else some other concatenation operation.

However, I am not finding an option here, like some built-in function.

Requirement is like

```
<Root>
  <a></a>
  <b></b>
  <c></c>
</Root>
```

Here is element `<a>`, come in request payload, then we need to perform concatenation of `<b>` and `<c>` else `<c>` and `<b>`.

Comment: kumarb, in case you did not understand this hint: Please accept one of the answers below before asking new questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with template matching:

```
<xsl:template match="Root[not(a)]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(c, b)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Root[a]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(b, c)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it along these lines:

```
<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="a">
            <!-- do something -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- do something else -->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

**Explanation**: the test returns the Boolean value of the node-set selected by the expression `a`. If the node-set is non-empty, the result is true.

Answer (score 1):

Test for the presence of the element, using `xsl:choose`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/Root"> 
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="a">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(c, b)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(b, c)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>  
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or in a predicate for template matches:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/Root[a]"> 
         <xsl:value-of select="concat(c, b)"/> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Root[not(a)]"> 
         <xsl:value-of select="concat(b, c)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, use `choose` and test for the presence of `a` using `boolean()` on the according xpath.

```
<xsl:template match="Root">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="boolean(./a)">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(./b, ./c)" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(./c, ./b)" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```